# A function that takes a callback and creates a new version of the callback that can only be called once. Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, underscore.js

I trying to create a function, that takes another function as the argument, and creates a new version of the callback function that can only be called once.  Subsequent calls will return the output if the initial call.

This is along the lines of recreating the Underscore .once method.

Here is what I have thus far.  I have created a chargeCreditCard function.  I want to create a new version of this function that can only be called once (chargeOnce).  Explanation is appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit.  I want the once function to not rely on any code outside of the function to work (ie. an external counter variable).

```
var chargeCreditCard = function(num, price){
    return num*price;
};
function once (func) {
    var hasActionBeenCalled = false;
    var call = function () { 
        if(!hasActionBeenCalled) {
            hasActionBeenCalled = true;
            func;
        }
    }
}
var chargeOnce = once(chargeCreditCard);  
console.log(chargeOnce(2,3));
console.log(chargeOnce(4,5));
```

Comment: I want the once function to exist independently.  Thus I can reuse it to "onceify" different functions as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `once` does not return anything, and your function `call` does not call anything. Make it

```
function once(func) {
    var hasActionBeenCalled = false;
    return function() { 
        if (!hasActionBeenCalled) {
            hasActionBeenCalled = true;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

For garbage collection, I'd recommend to do

```
function once(func) {
    var res;
    return function() { 
        if (typeof func == "function") {
            res = func.apply(this, arguments);
            func = null; // unset func
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi.  Is there a way to make this work without using .apply?

Comment: @mferg: No, why would you want to?

Comment: Well, you might be able to `return func` (and in the else-case `return function(){}`) and then call it like `console.log(chargeOnce()(4,5))`, but that would look odd.

Comment: Makes sense.  Also, how could I alter this function so all subsequent called return the output of the first call?

Comment: @mferg: I've adopted my second snippet to do that (after having realized that I had forgotten `var` anyway)